# Executing cron job for python fail when it has file acess

Tags: python, cron

I wanted to execute my python file every 10 minutes. I am working with ubuntu instance. This statement is t working until the line of the file acess. I couldn't figure out the problem. I have tested this to /usr/bin/`python` to `python3` and `python3.6` as well

```
   */10 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/ubuntu/Deploy/sam.py >> /home/ubuntu/test.log
```

The file acess doesn't work. How to give the file acess ?

sam.py

```
print('HI')
with open("EsText.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write("kugan")
    myfile.close()
```

Comment: Is this output file generated ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CronJob not running](/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running)

Comment: @ShivamSeth no! it's not executing !

Comment: Can u do 2 things  1st Manually run sam.py and check there is no issues, 2nd  execute sam.py and add lon sleep and try to find if process is actually running if yes then instead of externally redirect o/p try logging inside code

Comment: Can you access `/var/log/syslog`? If so, try grepping it for "cron". Also, you're running from the `/home/ubuntu/Deploy` directory, but writing to `/home/ubuntu`. Do you have write permissions to that latter directory?

Comment: @GreenMatt the print staement wroking . but there after that file write is not executing!

Comment: @eaglerocks: So it seems your cron job can write to that directory, but there's a problem in your program. As Shivam said, run the program from the command line and figure out what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

your cron expression should be `0 0/10 * 1/1 * ? *`
You can take help from [this](http://www.cronmaker.com/)

also try using `>` instead of `>>`

Comment: This will do every ten minutes from where you start the cronjob. His format is correct if he wants it on every 10th minute

Comment: It's not working. It's saying there's error. try this it's giving correct one https://crontab-generator.org/ @Rahul